# How to add a new textfield on clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm trying to insert certain sentences to MySQL database using PHP. But the design of the field is such a way that it shows only one field and a `[add]` button to insert a new textfield. So depending on the user needs, the number of textfields varies.

```
<div class="row">
  <h5>LEARNING GOALS</h5>
    <div style="display:table; width:100%;">
      <div style="display:table-row;">
        <div style="display:table-cell;">
           <input class="text-field" name="goal" type="text" placeholder="Goals*" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;width:65px;">
           <input class="add-field-btn" type="button" value="+" style="width:65px;"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

How can I add a new textfiled and assign name value and when I click on the submit button, to save all the textfield values into the database?

Comment: Yes I did. But I couldn't find it

Comment: Also what is the point of using divs with table display instead of actually using a table?

Comment: Trying to create a responsive design. DOn't want to use the table

Comment: There is practically no difference in how elements will display between the way you're doing it and using a table

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery add / remove</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    div{
        padding:8px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>jQuery add / remove </h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
     });

     $("#removeButton").click(function () {
    if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   

    counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

     });

     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

    var msg = '';
    for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
    }
          alert(msg);
     });
  });
</script>
</head><body>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qqVGu/142/) Check this fiddle.

```
document.getElementById('#whereToAppend').append('<input type="text" name="WhateverYouwant"/>');

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild('<input type="text"/>');
```

If you want dynamic names, set a class name or id to the input. And make use of `setAttribute` in javascript to set the name

Comment: How can I assign the name to each new textfield?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to try and serialize all the inputs and save them to the database. You just send them by submitting the form then in PHP do something like:

```
$inputs = serialize($_GET); // $inputs = serialize($_POST);
mysql_query('INSERT INTO `table` SET inputs = "'.$inputs.'"'); // try to validate the variable before
```

This would be nice given the fact that you have variable number of fields.
When you select them use `deserialize` to recreate the data:

```
$r = mysql_query('SELECT inputs FROM `table`');
...
$data = deserialize($row['inputs']);
```

---

Another option would be to get all the inputs with JavaScript or jQuery and pass them via AJAX.

```
var _data = [];
$('input.text-field').each(function(i, e) {
    _data.push($(e).val());
});

$.post('file.php', { d : JSON.stringify(_data)}, function(e){
     alert(e);
})
```

**PHP:**

```
$d = json_decode($_POST['d']);

foreach($d as $k => $v) {
   // value of the input no. $k is $v
}
```

---

You can use @Nickunj's jQuery code for appending the new input.

Comment: Can you explain me the AJAX method also

Answer (score 0):

First of all use your text field name as a array so when user will add new text field you can get all of them in just one post variable and you can store them in different row or as you want.

Now on click on you button append text field with same name as

```
your first field code:<input class="text-field" name="goal[]" type="text" placeholder="Goals*" style="width:100%">

Javascript code: $('#yourselector').append('<input class="text-field" name="goal[]" type="text" placeholder="Goals*" style="width:100%">');
```

It the server end you can get all the posted values in $_POST['goal'] which will be a array;